# Is there a way to get addresses back from Bing SOAP Search Service?

Tags: soap, windows-phone-7, geocoding, bing-maps

I'm currently using [Bing's SOAP Search Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980849.aspx) in order to get points of interest around a certain location. However, the return items only have a [GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980892.aspx) for the location, not an address.

The program is a WP7 app that maps POI, so I'd also like to show the address of the places found to the user. Is the only way to do this to make subsequent calls to Bing's Geocode service for each of the lat/long results? This seems like it would be time consuming and inefficient unless I could do a batch geocode call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The framework teasingly includes the [CivicAddressResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.civicaddressresolver%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), which would appear to perform this task for us, but unfortunately, the documentation also states:

> This class is not implemented in the current release.

However, all is not lost. You can use the same Bing search service that you are already using to reverse geocode a location by sending a `ReverseGeocodeRequest` as described in the [Developing a Silverlight Application Using Bing Maps SOAP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879136.aspx) under the **Reverse Geocoding** section.

For another detailed walkthrough (including code), take a look at Nick Harris' blog post: [How to Reverse Geocode a Location to an Address on Windows Phone 7](http://www.nickharris.net/?s=CivicAddressResolver&submit=Find)

Comment: Hopefully they'll implement the CivicAddressResolver in the future - I actually realized I was not casting the SearchResultBase class to BusinessSearchResult, which actually gives you the address.

Answer (score 0):

After looking closer, I realized I needed to cast the [SearchResultBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980892.aspx) result I was getting back to [BusinessSearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966876.aspx), which gave an address back.